# How can I count how many child nodes there are in a root xml tag in flex?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, root

Could I see an example on how to count how many child nodes there are under a root xml tag in flex?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`xml.children().length()`, where xml is an XML object. But it will count only first-level depth children. Do you need to count **all** the children?